# Some interesting Arqade vote statistics

Tags: discussion

In this post, I'll compare some vote statistics from [Arqade](http://gaming.stackexchange.com), [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com) and [Worldbuilding](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com) Stackexchange sites. Out-standing values are boldened:

#### Highest voted posts:

- **Arqade**

  1. [How can I tell if a corpse is safe to eat?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4999/how-can-i-tell-if-a-corpse-is-safe-to-eat) - **392** votes, 22k views
  2. [Is Angry Birds deterministic?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/44595/is-angry-birds-deterministic) - 303 votes, 19k views
  3. [Where is the "impossible space" in Portal 2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20601/where-is-the-impossible-space-in-portal-2) - 252 votes, 34k views
- **Ask Ubuntu**

  1. [How to list all installed packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages) - **904** votes, **1.4m** views
  2. [How can PPAs be removed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed) - **679** votes, 636k views
  3. [What Application Indicators are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/what-application-indicators-are-available) - **655** votes, 485k views
- **Worldbuilding**

  1. [Tomorrow is Groundhog Day… For everyone. How does society respond? [closed]](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/18051/tomorrow-is-groundhog-day-for-everyone-how-does-society-respond) - **220** votes, 16k views
  2. [How do you prove you're from the future?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/12348/how-do-you-prove-youre-from-the-future) - 205 votes, 31k views
  3. [How would Facebook Sysadmins prevent the summoning of Cthulhu?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/31388/how-would-facebook-sysadmins-prevent-the-summoning-of-cthulhu) - 173 votes, 20k views

#### Upvoted, downvoted and zero-voted questions:

- **Arqade**

  - All questions: 71k
  - Upvoted questions: 59.6k (**84%**)
  - Zero-voted questions: 8.7k (12%)
  - Downvoted questions: 2.7k (4%)
- **Ask Ubuntu**

  - All questions: **242k**
  - Upvoted questions: 138k (57%)
  - Zero-voted questions: 97.5k (**40%**)
  - Downvoted questions: 6.5k (3%)
- **Worldbuilding**

  - All questions: 8000
  - Upvoted questions: 7300 (**91%**)
  - Zero-voted questions: 350 (**4.5%**)
  - Downvoted questions: 350 (**4.5%**)

#### Biggest Upvoters

- **Arqade**

  1. [Robotnik ♦](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/28182/robotnik) - 8377 upvotes
  2. [Ullallulloo](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/118/ullallulloo) - 6104 upvotes
  3. [Brant](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/274/brant) - 6035 upvotes
- **Ask Ubuntu**

  1. [Jorge Castro](https://askubuntu.com/users/235/jorge-castro) - **24865 upvotes**
  2. [Seth ♦](https://askubuntu.com/users/44179/seth) - 15846 upvotes
  3. [Eliah Kagan](https://askubuntu.com/users/22949/eliah-kagan) - 13816 upvotes
- **Worldbuilding**

  1. [Tim B ♦](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/49/tim-b) - 6112 upvotes
  2. [Vincent](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/147/vincent) - 4609 upvotes
  3. [gnat](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/21198/gnat) - 3362 upvotes; 0 downvotes (!)

#### Biggest downvoters

- **Arqade**

  1. [Frank](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/20456/frank) - 20849 downvotes
  2. [Studoku](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/53291/studoku) - 3821 downvotes
  3. [kotekzot](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/19827/kotekzot) - 3134 downvotes
- **Ask Ubuntu**

  1. [Eric Carvalho](https://askubuntu.com/users/65926/eric-carvalho) - **29219 downvotes**
  2. [Braiam](https://askubuntu.com/users/169736/braiam) - 7503 downvotes
  3. [Eliah Kagan](https://askubuntu.com/users/22949/eliah-kagan) - 3781 downvotes
- **Worldbuilding**

  1. [Vincent](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/147/vincent) - 680 downvotes
  2. [HDE 226868 ♦](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/627/hde-226868) - 157 downvotes
  3. ? (all others had <100 downvotes)

Altogether (I also collected some data for stackoverflow.com and some other sites):

- We tend to vote more then on other sites:

  - an average upvoted question on Arquade has about 7 votes, an average answer a bit more. That's both **more then average** across stackexchange.
  - An average downvoted question has about -5 votes; and an answer about -2. Again, that's *more* downvotes then SE on average.
- **Our votes/views ratio is much better, then the SE average** - moving around 1 vote per 200-500 views. The SE average is 1 vote per 1000 views. That means we get less traffic from search engines then the SE average.
- About users... *Anyhow* a user votes, it is perfectly OK (except "oh, a nice meta post... wait, it's from this user I hate... -1").
- We have more percent of users with the Vox Populi tag than almost any SE site.

**So, I would like to say, that this community is awesome. good voting, keep it up!**

PS. Please, please, don't downvote because you see your name here - it's disrespectful. It took me hours of work to make this.

Comment: Am I missing some context? Is there a question here? Or a point you're trying to make?

Comment: I'm not sure what point you are trying to make, but Worldbuilding is a much newer site, so that's kind of an apples and oranges comparison.

Comment: Thanks I guess, but a user's votes (up or down) don't mean much by themselves :-). Someone could've voted more by virtue of having been a member longer than someone else. If you want to see how they skew compared to the rest of the site it's better to look at their voting ratio. IIRC there's a SEDE query that does it. *Edit: [Here it is](https://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/query/466049/upvote-downvote-ratio)*

Comment: @Robotnik I know; I used the absolute vote count on purpose. I also considered what you said, but didn't add it after all.

Comment: @murgatroid99 It's just *statistics*. You make the observations yourself. Also, a close vote is not a super-downvote

Comment: @Ash I just took 2 other sites at random to compare.

Comment: Not sure we should be singling people out for high upvotes or downvotes.  I'm pretty sure the numbers are justified (in terms of time on the site, and their motives for ensuring quality).

Comment: @RudolfL.Jelínek There is, however, a, "I have no idea what it is you're trying to convey" close reason.  This information serves no purpose on it's own.  You've made no attempt at providing a coherent point or argument as to the relevancy of this information.

Comment: @camelCase This **is not against ANYBODY**. I'm not saying anybody is worse/better. Everybody is different and has his stuff. This is just **facts**...

Comment: @Frank This is just data that I collected. Everybody sees different, so I didn't add any summary...

Comment: @Frank As for the point - it just shows mainly interesting stuff. You are, as I see it now, and please, *please* don't take this as an offence, saying me to not post anything, not comment or edit - "this site is only like a book for random people googling their problems." As for the `I see no reason to do so.` part, I didn't ask you to do anything - just to answer the comment. Please don't be hostile towards me. Thanks for sharing your opinion.

Comment: I'm not being hostile at all.  I'm pointing out that *there is no relevancy* to this information.  It has no purpose.  Meta isn't a place to post random stats for no reason.  Great.  So some sites have lots of questions.  Others don't.  You're comparing information that has no connections.

Comment: Statistics alone don't have meaning. They are just numbers representing some arbitrarily chosen set of facts. The meaning comes from using those statistics to back up a thesis or argument. So unless you're using statistics to make a point, sharing them is pointless.

Comment: @RudolfL.Jelínek - My problem was that you have selected to show a small sample of data, including the naming of top upvoters and downvoters, and then asked people to draw conclusions from your sample.  As well as the data not being complete (i.e. it is a sample of select data you wish to show) and that people are named specifically, it could create unfair criticism against certain members.

Answer (score 8):

[image]

Comment: Did you make this yourself?

Comment: @RudolfL.Jelínek the parts that obviously differ from the original piece are mine

Comment: I don't know the original; I found online a one with flames using Google.

Comment: @RudolfL.Jelínek http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/this-is-fine

Comment: @DJPirtu Thanks.